# String replace is not printing the value in console

Tags: java

I've an HTML File as below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="er:#css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
</head>
<body class="text" id="text">
<div class="chapter">
<a id="page1" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to replace `a id` with `id num` and using the below code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String input = "file:///C:/Users/users/file.html";

        URL url= new URL(input);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (inputLine.contains("a id")) {
                inputLine.replace("a id", "?pb label =");
            }
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        }
    }
```

But when I print it in the console, it doesn't replace the data. I get the below output.

```
<html>
```

Title

the word is not getting replaced. When I did a `debug`, `If-loop` is entered in this case, the the data is not replaced in console.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: as a sidenote, while this might work, using a proper html parser might be a better solution.

Comment: I don't know why nothing is printed to the console (since after skimming over your code i think that indeed it should do so), but inputLine.replace does not replace the contents of the current String object but returns the result as a new string object. so `inputline = inputline.replace(...` is the first thing that you should fix in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String` is immutable. You must assign the result of `replace` back to `inputLine`, since `replace` returns a new `String` :

```
inputLine = inputLine.replace("a id", "?pb label =");
```